# An example to show that the order of gN in G/N maybe strictly smaller than the order of g in G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

G is a group and N is a normal subgroup. G/N is the quotient group.

P.s if anyone can tell me how to be systematic with my studies in abstract algebra, I mean topic wise or otherwise, it will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g \in N$ and $g \ne e$.  Then the order of $g$ is greater than one, but the order of $gN$ is one.

This fails if $N=\{e\}$, but in that case your desired result also fails, so it's the best you can do.

Comment: I thought about this, but it's just trivially giving the answer as "g" is getting absorbed in N. I mean, is there any other answer where g is an element of G but not N ?

Comment: Try the cyclic group of order $4$ with $|N|=2$.